# Javaでのデータベース操作のSQL文の書き方

Tags: java, sql

Javaでローカルでデータベースを立ち上げ、name num priceの三つの項目が入っているTestテーブルがあるとして、このテーブルから`num*price`の売上金額が一番多いもののnameを取り出したいのですが、`num*price`の売上金額が同額で一番多いものが二つ以上ある場合には、その二つを取り出せるようにしたいです。これはSQL文だけで実行可能でしょうか。それともJavaのプログラムで実行することしかできないでしょうか。SQLで実行可能な場合はどのような書き方になるか教えていただきたいです。

Comment: 「`num*price` の売上金額が一番多いもののnameを 〜 同額で一番多いものが二つ以上ある場合には、その二つを取り出せる 〜」をそのまま SQL で表現すればよいかと。テーブル名を `goods` だとして、`SELECT name FROM goods WHERE (num*price) = (SELECT MAX(num*price) FROM goods);`

Comment: @metropolis　うまく動きました。where句の書き方の部分で(num*price) = (SELECT MAX(num*price)こんな書き方ができるんですね。コメントで回答いただきましたが、回答は自分で記載すればよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: はい、そうして下さい。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

metropolis さんのコメントより、テーブル名を goods だとして、以下の通り実行することで実現できました。

```sql
SELECT name FROM goods WHERE (num*price) = (SELECT MAX(num*price) FROM goods);
```